# How to disable in flutter stepper the first cancel button

Tags: flutter

I currently have a stepper that also works perfectly, but I have the question how to disable the back button at the first step, but in the others it should be displayed.

I modified the stepper with the controlsBuilder but i didnt found a solution where i can disable the back button.

Thanks in advance

Here is a small code snippet from my stepper (not fully):

````
 controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                    {VoidCallback onStepContinue, VoidCallback onStepCancel}) {
                  return Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton(
                        onPressed: onStepContinue,
                        child: const Text('Weiter',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                        color: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                      new Padding(
                        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      ),
                      FlatButton(
                        onPressed: onStepCancel,
                        child: const Text(
                          'Zurück',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        color: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },



List<Step> steps = [
      Step(
        title: const Text('TEST'),
        isActive: true,
        state: StepState.complete,
        content: Column(children: <Widget>[
          RadioListTile(
            value: 1,
            groupValue: selectedRadioTile,
            title: Text("XX"),
            onChanged: (val) {
              setSelectedRadioTile(val);
            },
            activeColor: Colors.blue,
            selected: true,
          ),
          RadioListTile(
            value: 2,
            groupValue: selectedRadioTile,
            title: Text("XX"),
            onChanged: (val) {
              setSelectedRadioTile(val);
            },
            activeColor: Colors.blue,
            selected: false,
          ),
        ]),
      ),```
````

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to disable the "Cancel" button conditionally.

You will somehow need to know whether it is the first screen or not. Let's say you have that in a variable called `isFirstScreen` that you pass to your `controlsBuilder` method. Then you can disable the button with a ternary operator on the `onPressed` handler like this:

```dart
FlatButton(
  onPressed: isFirstScreen ? null : onStepCancel, // <-- important part
  child: const Text(
    'Zurück',
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
  ),
  color: Colors.blue,
),
```

From the Flutter [FlatButton docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FlatButton-class.html):

> If the onPressed callback is null, then the button will be disabled, will not react to touch, and will be colored as specified by the disabledColor property instead of the color property.

Comment: If it works, please mark this answer as the solution so others can find it more quickly in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**In Flutter Version: 2.10.0**

**Just initialize a boolean variable globally**

bool hide = true;

**Then,**

```
  controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context, ControlsDetails details) {
          return Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                onPressed: details.onStepContinue,
                child: Text(hide == true ? '' : 'Confirm'),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: details.onStepCancel,
                child: Text(hide == true ? '' :'Cancel'),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
```

*it will disappear 'Confirm' as well as 'Cancel' button. If you have no need these actually.*

Comment: One small advice. We don't compare boolean variables to true or false, we just test the boolean variable. Instead of `if (hide == true) ...` we write `if (hide) ...`. We should also rename the variable `hide` to `hidden`. :)